# Why are the totals different before and after aggregating in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I have a large database with ID as the first column. The second variable, EventName, is a time series. So IDs will overlap within each time series. The following variables identify the primary and duplicates for each unique ID. The following variable are MH Diagnoses (0=no; 1=yes) for each time period. The TypeMH goes up to 25. The last variable in the example below is a sum of the 1s for all MHTypes 1-25.

When I run a frequency count on the whole database for each MH Type, I get one number for counts of TypeMH1. But when I aggregate the IDs to sum all of the same IDs, the frequency count is lower. See picture 2.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

I've tried running the aggregate by sum and by counts. Same results.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the "frequency count" counting after the aggregation? In any case please add an example to your question - see an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - better and clearer questions will get you (better) answers. Also preparing the example will sometimes help you discover the answer by yourself...

Comment: Edited to include example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in the outputs, the first `frequencies` ran on the summing variable `New_MH_After_Entry_Counts`, which doesn't differentiate between the `typemho` variables - just sums them. The label you marked in yellow is **wrong**. What that line in the table actually means is that in 137 lines in the dataset the sum of `typemho___1` to `typemho___25` is 1.
This number has nothing to do with 223, which is the number of lines marked 1 in `typemho___1` (as presented in the second frequency analysis).

Comment: Thank you! Posting another question now in a separate thread. :-)